# GWT Guava classloader issue with AbstractMapBasedMultimap

Tags: java, gwt, guava

I have added both guava libs (guava*-14.0.jar) to my GWT 2.5.0 project + inherits in module definition. Afterwards I get following error after deployment to server

```
[#|2013-03-01T16:56:02.041+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=96;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|WebModule[/GlnToolNight]Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
java.lang.VerifyError: class com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultimap overrides final method setMap.(Ljava/util/Map;)V
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
```

java.runtime.version = 1.7.0_09-b05

Java 7 is not supported by guava? How can I fix it?

Comment: Could this be an issue with GWT and JDK 7?

Comment: that could be the answer, but on the page there is "Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java 1.6+"

Comment: plain GWT works fine with JDK7, this problem comes only after adding guava to module definition (<inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect"/> )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like Glassfish is misbundling Guava. I've posted more on [the Guava bug thread](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1318).